# Is there an efficient way to get the values of an object from an array of objects based on a key value pair

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to JavaScript and I am stuck.
I have an array of objects below

```
const   items = [
{
  "product": "apple",
  "quantity": 3
},
{
  "product": "orange",
  "quantity": 1
},
{
  "product": "mango",
  "quantity": 0.6
},
{
  "product": "pineapple",
  "quantity": 52
},
{
  "product": "banana",
  "quantity": 23
},
{
  "product": "avocado",
  "quantity": 14
}
```

]

I am trying to display these on a table and would like to get the quantity for each row based on the product, so if for instance it is a row for banana, I get 23.

What I have attempted so far is

```
 function specs(gizmo){
   var found = items.filter(obj => obj.product === gizmo);
   return found[0]?.quantity
 }

  console.log(specs('banana'));
```

This works if I hard-code the array, but when I pull it from Firestore, which is my Backend. I get the error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

I have tried adding a fallback but that still fails to work.

Comment: can u log found. it is probably empty array. btw why not use find instead of filter since u are looking for 1 element in the array

Comment: use `find` instead of `filter` if you just want the first item.

Comment: found shows undefined for a second before it pulls from firestore, but then gets the data afterwards. Please show me how to use -find- on the array of objects

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call for getting the results of the async call to Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

For you use case you should use [`array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Note that you will still need to use optional chaining since the returned value could be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

As others already mentioned, use `find()` instead.

You can also create a custom function that loops trough the array and searches for the item. I made an example below.

```
function specs(itemToFind) {
  for(const item of items) {
    if(item.product === itemToFind) {
      return item;
    }
  }
  
  return null; // return something else if item was not found.
}

console.log(specs("banana"));
```